# VS Code Remote Xdebug session disconnects after 600+ seconds

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-8, xdebug

I have a Laravel 8 PHP application.
I am having an annoying issue, where sometimes I may need to leave a test running in debug mode for a long time, but the session disconnects, after I suspect 600 seconds.

The app runs in docker container, I have a helper script that runs PHPUnit tests like so:

```
./sam test tests/Api/UnpublishTest.php --filter shouldUnpublishFormOnMoveQuestion --configuration phpunit.xml
```

of which the relevant part is:

```bash
elif [ "$1" == "test" ]; then
    shift 1
    $COMPOSE exec \
        app \
        ./vendor/bin/phpunit "$@"
```

When `$COMPOSE` is defined as:

```bash
if [ -f $DIR/.env ]; then
    COMPOSE="docker-compose --env-file $DIR/.env --file $DIR/docker-compose.local.yml"
else
    COMPOSE="docker-compose --file $DIR/docker-compose.local.yml"
fi
```

The xdebug.ini settings:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

The VS Code debug configuration:

```json
{
    "name": "AppName Listen for Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/": "${workspaceFolder}/app_name"
    }
}
```

When I leave the session idle, here is the output, after Xdebug disconnects in VSCode on its own:

```
❯ ./sam test tests/Api/UnpublishTest.php --filter shouldUnpublishFormOnMoveQuestion --configuration phpunit.xml
PHPUnit 9.5.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.3.33
Configuration: phpunit.xml

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 10:26.537, Memory: 30.00 MB
```

Other times, it can be `10:25.914` - it looks suspiciously close to some default of 600 secs (10 mins) somewhere.

I've searched the Xdebug config docs and I cant find anything related to timeout.

What could it be?
I want to set it so no matter how long I've left the session, it wont timeout the debugger and continue executing until I am ready to resume!

Thanks.

Answering comments questions:

When xdebug log level is set to 10, it runs infinitely repeating the same block in logs, not disconnecting in CS Code, so I killed it when the log reached 135mb. A repeat attempt where I was busy for longer, resulted in 1.5gb logs and crashed vs code due to the log file being open :)

```
[11724] Log opened at 2023-03-09 17:22:48.047751
[11724] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[11724] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.33" protocol_version="1.0" appid="11724"><engine version="3.1.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- feature_get -i 4 -n breakpoint_include_return_value
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="4" feature_name="breakpoint_include_return_value" supported="0"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n max_children -v 100
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file:///var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php -n 42
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="117240001" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php -n 94
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="117240002" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t line -f file:///var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php -n 162
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="117240003" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t line -f file:///var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php -n 169
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="117240004" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t line -f file:///var/www/tests/Api/UnpublishTest.php -n 140
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="10" id="117240005" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 11 -t line -f file:///var/www/tests/Api/UnpublishTest.php -n 146
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="11" id="117240006" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 12 -t line -f file:///var/www/app/Http/Forms/MoveQuestionForm.php -n 21
[11724] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="12" id="117240007" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11724] [Step Debug] <- run -i 13
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:42.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:42' against location '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15'.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (27) doesn't match with breakpoint (47).
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:94.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:94' against location '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15'.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (27) doesn't match with breakpoint (47).
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:162.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:162' against location '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15'.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (27) doesn't match with breakpoint (47).
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:169.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:169' against location '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15'.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (27) doesn't match with breakpoint (47).
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/tests/Api/UnpublishTest.php:140.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/tests/Api/UnpublishTest.php:140' against location '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15'.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (27) doesn't match with breakpoint (36).
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/tests/Api/UnpublishTest.php:146.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/tests/Api/UnpublishTest.php:146' against location '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15'.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (27) doesn't match with breakpoint (36).
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/app/Http/Forms/MoveQuestionForm.php:21.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/app/Http/Forms/MoveQuestionForm.php:21' against location '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:15'.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (27) doesn't match with breakpoint (44).
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:42.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:16.
[11724] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/app/Http/Utils/QuestionsRearranger.php:42' against location '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit:16'.
```

This keeps repeating endlessly

Tried again with Log level 3, then got distracted by another meeting and here are results:

```
[11748] Log opened at 2023-03-09 19:50:02.019916
[11748] [Step Debug] WARN: 2023-03-09 20:05:37.961656: There was a problem sending 322 bytes on socket 3: Broken pipe.
[11748] [Step Debug] WARN: 2023-03-09 20:05:38.395565: There was a problem sending 179 bytes on socket 3: Broken pipe.
[11748] Log closed at 2023-03-09 20:05:38.409721
```

Console output:
`Time: 15:30.535, Memory: 32.00 MB`

I am not sure what else to try, what is causing it not to disconnect and have endless cyclical log output at log level 10?

Comment: Xdebug does not have a time out, but perhaps VS Code has. Can you make an Xdebug log (`xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` && `xdebug.log_level=10` in php.ini)?

Comment: Personally I do not think it's Xdebug and I do not remember any Xdebug config options for this. If it would be a web page debug, we could think about web server/(Fast)CGI module settings (there are for killing processes that have no activity/output for a certain duration). But it's a CLI process... So **I think** it could be either PHPUnit or VSCode. Please enable Xdebug logging `xdebug.log`, start debugging and reproduce the results -- see if there will be anything in the logs (if it's VSCode then it should send some commands to detach or alike)

Comment: @Derick I've added the requested logging as much as I could - see the amended edit description. It runs endlessly generating massive log files repeating the same stuff more or less.

Comment: Actually ... focus on your PHP code. Why wouldn't that have a timeout? How about your php.ini? Think about why you want to test your process that way. Do you have any breakpoints in the code?